# How do I assign reference field

Tags: c#, ref

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public X x;
    string name;
    string someInfo;
    public SomeClass(string name,...)
    {
       //....
    }
}
public class X
{
}

SomeClass a = new SomeClass(~~~);
SomeClass b = new SomeClass(~~~);

a.x = new X();    //this new X instance call X1
b.x = a.x;        //a.x = b.x => X1


a.x = new X();    //this new X instance call X2
                  //a.x == X2   b.x== X1
                  //b.x doesn't change when a.x changed.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
a.x = new X(); //a.x= b.x =>X2 - this what i want.
```

I wnat to point out that b.x has the same address a.x .
If it's a C language, just point it out.
but in C#, ref keyword can use only parameter.
How can b.x have an address of an a.x?

ok. added infomation.

instance of a has 0x0000
instance of b has 0x0100
if `a.x = new X()` then a.x pointed X instance : 0xF000
Then `b.x = a.x` then b.x pointed X instance : 0xF000 Not a.x's adress:0x0000 + sizeof(X)
I want to b.x has a.x's Ardress. Not Value's Adress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is **no native way to store a reference to a variable in C#**. Luckily, there are many ways to have `b`'s X object reference stay in sync with `a`'s X object reference.

First, the classes:

```
  public class SomeClass
  {
    public X x;
  }

  public class X
  {
    public int i; // I added this int to verify which X object we're working with.
    public X(int i)
    {
      this.i = i;
    }
  }
```

## Scenario 1: If you need to reference a new X object.

Option 1: If `a` and `b` need to be different SomeClass objects, you can simply update `b`'s X object reference to `a`'s X object reference.

```
  SomeClass a = new SomeClass();
  SomeClass b = new SomeClass();

  a.x = new X(1);
  b.x = a.x;
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x.i:{a.x.i}, b.x.i:{b.x.i}"); // a.x.i:1, b.x.i:1
  a.x = new X(2);
  b.x = a.x;
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x.i:{a.x.i}, b.x.i:{b.x.i}"); // a.x.i:2, b.x.i:2
```

Option 2: If `b` doesn't need to be different than `a`, have `b` reference the same SomeClass object that `a` does.

```
  SomeClass a = new SomeClass();
  SomeClass b = a;

  a.x = new X(1);
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x.i:{a.x.i}, b.x.i:{b.x.i}"); // a.x.i:1, b.x.i:1
  a.x = new X(2);
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x.i:{a.x.i}, b.x.i:{b.x.i}"); // a.x.i:2, b.x.i:2
```

## Scenario 2: If you only need to modify an internal value of the X object.

Since `a.x` is the same X object as `b.x`, you can modify that object using either reference and view that change using the other reference.

```
  SomeClass a = new SomeClass();
  SomeClass b = new SomeClass();

  a.x = new X(1);
  b.x = a.x;
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x.i:{a.x.i}, b.x.i:{b.x.i}"); // a.x.i:1, b.x.i:1
  a.x.i = 2;
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x.i:{a.x.i}, b.x.i:{b.x.i}"); // a.x.i:2, b.x.i:2
  b.x.i = 3;
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x.i:{a.x.i}, b.x.i:{b.x.i}"); // a.x.i:3, b.x.i:3
```

## Scenario 3: If you want a different class to always have easy access to `a`'s X object.

New class:

```
  public class SomeClass2
  {
    private SomeClass someClass;
    public X x { get { return someClass.x; } }
    public SomeClass2(SomeClass sc)
    {
      someClass = sc;
    }
  }
```

Using the new class:

```
  SomeClass a = new SomeClass();
  SomeClass2 b = new SomeClass2(a);

  a.x = new X(1);
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x.i:{a.x.i}, b.x.i:{b.x.i}"); // a.x.i:1, b.x.i:1
  a.x = new X(2);
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x.i:{a.x.i}, b.x.i:{b.x.i}"); // a.x.i:2, b.x.i:2
```

## Scenario 4: If you want a local alias to `a.x`.

```
  SomeClass a = new SomeClass();

  Func<X> func = () => a.x; // "func()" is now essentially an alias of "a.x"
  a.x = new X(1);
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x.i:{a.x.i}, func().i:{func().i}"); // a.x.i:1, func().i:1
  a.x = new X(2);
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x.i:{a.x.i}, func().i:{func().i}"); // a.x.i:2, func().i:2
```

## Scenario 5: If you need to use the same class and have `b.x` always reference the same object as `a.x`.

You can use a `Func<X>` member of your class to act like similarly to a variable reference. This works **but I don't necessarily recommend doing it** because it is not intuitive and can cause confusion.

The class:

```
  public class SomeClass3
  {
    public Func<X> x;
  }
```

Using the class:

```
  SomeClass3 a = new SomeClass3();
  SomeClass3 b = new SomeClass3();

  X x1 = new X(1);
  a.x = () => x1;
  b.x = () => a.x();
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x().i:{a.x().i}, b.x().i:{b.x().i}"); // a.x().i:1, b.x().i:1
  X x2 = new X(2);
  a.x = () => x2;
  Console.WriteLine($"a.x().i:{a.x().i}, b.x().i:{b.x().i}"); // a.x().i:2, b.x().i:2
```

Comment: `no native way to store a reference to a variable in C#` That's what i want. i'll try Sc4. Great Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword creates a new instance of class `X`

Instead of creating a new object and assigning it to `a.x`, you should simply modify the internal value of the instance of `x`

```
a.x.name = "2";
```

Comment: i mean Same Address, not value. i don't want a.x.name == b.x.name

Answer (score 0):

As you did for "X1", just do this again at the end:

`b.x = a.x;        //a.x = b.x => X2`

instead of

`a.x = new X();`

Comment: then a.x has X3 and b.x has X1. i'm not sure X1 is same X3

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you should say:

```
a = new SomClass();
b = a;
```

Now, if you set:

```
a.x = new X();
```

Now b.x will contain the same object as a.x (because b == a).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I assign reference field

You don't.  This is exactly why you should be using `Properties` not `Fields`.

> I want to point out that b.x has the same address a.x .

Well your code is completely invalid, so it really doesn't make sense:

```
a.x = new X();    //X1
b.x = a.x;        //a.x = b.x => X1
```

Where did `b` come from?  How was it initialized?  Why can you assign x?

This is probably an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858) because what you're doing, you've provided no value **why** this is important.  That being said this should work as you've described, but I've **never** had to write this code in the last 10 years so I suspect it's a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

```
public class X1 { }
public class SomeClass
{
  private static X1 _X = new X1();

  public X1 X 
  {
    get 
    {
      return _X;
    }
  }
}

var a = new SomeClass();
var b = new SomeClass();
Assert.That(a.X, Is.EqualTo(b.X)) // true, always
```

YMMV, this is really a bad pattern (the idea of the implementation).

Comment: X1 X2 just for distinction. And this code is a simplification. Think of it as a pseudocode.

Comment: if var c = new SomeClass(); and want to c.x != a.x then How??

Comment: I just Wanted know How to b.x has Same adress with a.x .  Not Static, Not a=b just like ref Keyword. Yes Someone said Using unsafe. but i know unsafe Not recommended. That's why asking This Question. i don't know why everyone giving to me a wild answer.